# Change border color navbar bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I want to remove this line see below image. I think it's border color but i did try to change color of border but still issue exist.

[See this Link for customization of bootstrap navbar](https://www.dropbox.com/s/biwcmpcomcv1dwu/issue.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: Can you post the code you tried?

Comment: Where is your code?? At least a JSFiddle!

Comment: When i check my code in bootply it shows no border but in browser it shows line below navbar.

Check out http://www.bootply.com/Y0DJWHUs7O

Comment: Check if the border comes from other CSS rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you really should include some code.

A typical bootstrap navbar gets the border from .navbar-default

So try the css below:

```
.navbar-default {
  border-color: transparent;}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of bootstrap menus - default or inverse (light or dark):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"></nav> 
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation"></nav>
```

According to your use, do something like this:

```
.navbar-default {border:none !Important;} or
.navbar-inverse {border:none !important;}
```